# Getting author to view correct story in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I'm using Laravel 7 and I'm  trying to create a site where the user can login if they have a token. I seem to have that almost working in that if you don't
have a token you can't access the page and if you put in a token that isn't in the database then it throws out an error.

The problem I'm having is that a user can still view a page they not meant to. For example I have Story 1 and Story 2, Author 1 can
view both Story 1 and 2, but Author 2 can only view Story 2.

The issue is that Author 2 can view both Story 1 and Story 2, which is wrong they only supposed to see Story 2.

I wanted to use middleware for this but I kind of hit a brick wall and not sure what next to do.

My tables

```
Story Table
id | title
1  | Story 1
2  | Story 2


Author Table
id | name
1  | Author 1
2  | Author 2

author_story table
id | author_id | story_id
1  |    1      |    1
2  |    1      |    2
3  |    2      |    2
```

My Story.php

```
protected $fillable = ['title'];

public function authors()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Author');
}
```

My Author.php

```
protected $fillable = ['name'];

public function stories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Story');
}
```

My ViewStory.php (middleware)

```
if(Auth::check())
{
    return $next($request);
}else{
    abort(401);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you get any error?

I think you should use hasMany relation in my author model:

```
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Story',story_id, id);
```